# Searching arrays based off multiple options selected in dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to build a finder which uses the selected options in a dropdown menu and from these particular selections searches an array (related to these selections) and displays a value on the html.
Im trying to use a for loop but Im having issues when I try to iterate through an array.
It is a lot of data and I'm not sure as to whether I should be using Ajax and JSON? Any advice would be really helpful.

Dropdown 1 Shows threaded/solder or flange/groove
Dropdown 2 Shows DN sizing
Dropdown 3 Shows no. of turns.

Basically threaded/solder has different values in its array for each DN sizing and No. of turns.

I would like to lose the submit button as well but its been helping me with trying to debug. I've cut the code down a heap there's still a lot of data to input into the arrays.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var list1 = document.getElementById('firstList');
  list1.options[0] = new Option('Valve Type', '');
  list1.options[1] = new Option('Thread/Solder', 'Thread/Solder');
  list1.options[2] = new Option('Flange/Groove', 'Flange/Groove');
});

function getValveSize() {
  var list1 = document.getElementById('firstList');
  var list2 = document.getElementById("secondList");
  var list1SelectedValue = list1.options[list1.selectedIndex].value;

  if (list1SelectedValue == 'Thread/Solder') {
    list2.options.length = 0;
    list2.options[0] = new Option('DN', '');
    list2.options[1] = new Option('10', '10');
    list2.options[2] = new Option('15', '15');
    list2.options[3] = new Option('20', '20');
    list2.options[4] = new Option('25', '25');
    list2.options[5] = new Option('32', '32');
    list2.options[6] = new Option('40', '40');
    list2.options[7] = new Option('50', '50');
    list2.options[8] = new Option('65', '65');
  } else if (list1SelectedValue == 'Flange/Groove') {
    list2.options.length = 0;
    list2.options[0] = new Option('DN', '');
    list2.options[1] = new Option('20', '20');
    list2.options[2] = new Option('25', '25');
    list2.options[3] = new Option('32', '32');
    list2.options[4] = new Option('40', '40');
    list2.options[5] = new Option('50', '50');
    list2.options[6] = new Option('65', '65');
    list2.options[7] = new Option('80', '80');
    list2.options[8] = new Option('100', '100');
    list2.options[9] = new Option('125', '125');
    list2.options[10] = new Option('150', '150');
    list2.options[11] = new Option('200', '200');
    list2.options[12] = new Option('250', '250');
    list2.options[13] = new Option('300', '300');
    list2.options[14] = new Option('350', '350');
    list2.options[15] = new Option('400', '400');
  }
}

function getTurns() {
  var list2 = document.getElementById('secondList');
  var list3 = document.getElementById('thirdList');
  var list2SelectedValue = list2.options[list2.selectedIndex].value;

  if ($.inArray(list2SelectedValue, ['10', '15', '20', '25']) >= 0) {
    list3.options.length = 0;
    list3.options[0] = new Option('Turns', '');
    list3.options[1] = new Option('0.25', '0.25');
    list3.options[2] = new Option('0.5', '0.5');
    list3.options[3] = new Option('0.75', '0.75');
    list3.options[4] = new Option('1', '1');
    list3.options[5] = new Option('1.1', '1.1');
    list3.options[6] = new Option('1.2', '1.2');
    list3.options[7] = new Option('1.3', '1.3');
    list3.options[8] = new Option('1.4', '1.5');
    list3.options[9] = new Option('1.6', '1.6');
    list3.options[10] = new Option('1.7', '1.7');
    list3.options[11] = new Option('1.8', '1.8');
    list3.options[12] = new Option('1.9', '1.9');
    list3.options[13] = new Option('2', '2');
    list3.options[14] = new Option('2.1', '2.1');
    list3.options[15] = new Option('2.2', '2.2');
    list3.options[16] = new Option('2.3', '2.3');
    list3.options[17] = new Option('2.4', '2.4');
    list3.options[18] = new Option('2.5', '2.5');
    list3.options[19] = new Option('2.6', '2.6');
    list3.options[20] = new Option('2.7', '2.7');
    list3.options[21] = new Option('2.8', '2.8');
    list3.options[22] = new Option('2.9', '2.9');
    list3.options[23] = new Option('3', '3');
  }

  if ($.inArray(list2SelectedValue, ['32', '40', '50']) >= 0) {
    list3.options.length = 0;
    list3.options[0] = new Option('Turns', '');
    list3.options[1] = new Option('0.25', '0.25');
    list3.options[2] = new Option('0.5', '0.5');
    list3.options[3] = new Option('0.75', '0.75');
    list3.options[4] = new Option('1', '1');
    list3.options[5] = new Option('1.1', '1.1');
    list3.options[6] = new Option('1.2', '1.2');
    list3.options[7] = new Option('1.3', '1.3');
    list3.options[8] = new Option('1.4', '1.5');
    list3.options[9] = new Option('1.6', '1.6');
    list3.options[10] = new Option('1.7', '1.7');
    list3.options[11] = new Option('1.8', '1.8');
    list3.options[12] = new Option('1.9', '1.9');
    list3.options[13] = new Option('2', '2');

    var threadedDn10Kv = [{
      '0.25': 0.21,
      '0.5': 0.34,
      '0.75': 0.40,
      '1': 0.46,
      '1.1': 0.48,
    }];

    var threadedDn15Kv = [{
      '0.25': 0.30,
      '0.5': 0.34,
      '0.75': 0.40,
      '1': 0.46,
      '1.1': 0.48,
      '1.2': 0.50,
    }]

    function findInArray(threadedDn10Kv, val) {
      var list2 = document.getElementById('secondList');
      var val = list2.options[list2.selectedIndex].value;
      for (var i = 0; i < threadedDn10Kv.length; i++) {
        if (threadedDn10Kv[i] === val) {
          document.getElementById('kvanswer').innerHTML = `Kv = ${i}`;

        }
      }
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <h1 class="calculatorcom">Valve calculations and conversions</h1><br><br>
  <h2>Oventropp valve Kv finder</h2><br>
  <h2 id="kvanswer"></h2>
</div>
<div class="valvetype">
  <select class="form-control" id='firstList' name='firstList' onClick="getValveSize()">
    <option>Type</option>
  </select>
  <select class="form-control" id='secondList' name='secondList' onClick="getTurns()">
    <option>DN</option>
  </select>
  <select class="form-control" id='thirdList' name='thirdList'>
    <option>Turns</option>
  </select>
  <button onclick="findInArray()">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Your code snippet is missing a bracket at the end

Comment: And also what exactly is the question? Whithout knowing the circumstances it is impossible to tell wheter you should filter server side

Comment: Apologies if I have not made the question clear. How can I use the selected options in the dropdown to filter arrays and return a value from the correct array. For example if choose threaded, DN 15  1.1 turns it returns 0.48 to the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var list1 = document.getElementById('firstList');
  list1.options[0] = new Option('Valve Type', '');
  list1.options[1] = new Option('Thread/Solder', 'Thread/Solder');
  list1.options[2] = new Option('Flange/Groove', 'Flange/Groove');
});

function getValveSize() {
  var list1 = document.getElementById('firstList');
  var list2 = document.getElementById("secondList");
  var list1SelectedValue = list1.options[list1.selectedIndex].value;

  if (list1SelectedValue == 'Thread/Solder') {
    list2.options.length = 0;
    list2.options[0] = new Option('DN', '');
    list2.options[1] = new Option('10', '10');
    list2.options[2] = new Option('15', '15');
    list2.options[3] = new Option('20', '20');
    list2.options[4] = new Option('25', '25');
    list2.options[5] = new Option('32', '32');
    list2.options[6] = new Option('40', '40');
    list2.options[7] = new Option('50', '50');
    list2.options[8] = new Option('65', '65');
  } else if (list1SelectedValue == 'Flange/Groove') {
    list2.options.length = 0;
    list2.options[0] = new Option('DN', '');
    list2.options[1] = new Option('20', '20');
    list2.options[2] = new Option('25', '25');
    list2.options[3] = new Option('32', '32');
    list2.options[4] = new Option('40', '40');
    list2.options[5] = new Option('50', '50');
    list2.options[6] = new Option('65', '65');
    list2.options[7] = new Option('80', '80');
    list2.options[8] = new Option('100', '100');
    list2.options[9] = new Option('125', '125');
    list2.options[10] = new Option('150', '150');
    list2.options[11] = new Option('200', '200');
    list2.options[12] = new Option('250', '250');
    list2.options[13] = new Option('300', '300');
    list2.options[14] = new Option('350', '350');
    list2.options[15] = new Option('400', '400');
  }
}

function getTurns() {
  // clear list
  $('#thirdList').empty();

  var list1 = document.getElementById('firstList');
  var list2 = document.getElementById('secondList');
  var list3 = document.getElementById('thirdList');
  var list2SelectedValue = list2.options[list2.selectedIndex].value;
  var list1SelectedValue = list1.options[list1.selectedIndex].value;

  if (list1SelectedValue === 'Thread/Solder') {
    if ($.inArray(list2SelectedValue, ['10', '15', '20', '25']) >= 0) {
      list3.options.length = 0;
      list3.options[0] = new Option('Turns', '');
      list3.options[1] = new Option('0.25', '0.25');
      list3.options[2] = new Option('0.5', '0.5');
      list3.options[3] = new Option('0.75', '0.75');
      list3.options[4] = new Option('1', '1');
      list3.options[5] = new Option('1.1', '1.1');
      list3.options[6] = new Option('1.2', '1.2');
      list3.options[7] = new Option('1.3', '1.3');
      list3.options[8] = new Option('1.4', '1.5');
      list3.options[9] = new Option('1.6', '1.6');
      list3.options[10] = new Option('1.7', '1.7');
      list3.options[11] = new Option('1.8', '1.8');
      list3.options[12] = new Option('1.9', '1.9');
      list3.options[13] = new Option('2', '2');
      list3.options[14] = new Option('2.1', '2.1');
      list3.options[15] = new Option('2.2', '2.2');
      list3.options[16] = new Option('2.3', '2.3');
      list3.options[17] = new Option('2.4', '2.4');
      list3.options[18] = new Option('2.5', '2.5');
      list3.options[19] = new Option('2.6', '2.6');
      list3.options[20] = new Option('2.7', '2.7');
      list3.options[21] = new Option('2.8', '2.8');
      list3.options[22] = new Option('2.9', '2.9');
      list3.options[23] = new Option('3', '3');
    }

    if ($.inArray(list2SelectedValue, ['32', '40', '50']) >= 0) {
      list3.options.length = 0;
      list3.options[0] = new Option('Turns', '');
      list3.options[1] = new Option('0.25', '0.25');
      list3.options[2] = new Option('0.5', '0.5');
      list3.options[3] = new Option('0.75', '0.75');
      list3.options[4] = new Option('1', '1');
      list3.options[5] = new Option('1.1', '1.1');
      list3.options[6] = new Option('1.2', '1.2');
      list3.options[7] = new Option('1.3', '1.3');
      list3.options[8] = new Option('1.4', '1.5');
      list3.options[9] = new Option('1.6', '1.6');
      list3.options[10] = new Option('1.7', '1.7');
      list3.options[11] = new Option('1.8', '1.8');
      list3.options[12] = new Option('1.9', '1.9');
      list3.options[13] = new Option('2', '2');
    }
  } else if (list1SelectedValue === 'Flange/Groove') {
    list3.options[0] = new Option('other option set', 'other option set');
  }

  $('#thirdList').append(list3);
}


var threaded = {
  '10': {
    '0.25': 0.21,
    '0.5': 0.34,
    '0.75': 0.40,
    '1': 0.46,
    '1.1': 0.48,
  },
  '15': {
    '0.25': 0.30,
    '0.5': 0.34,
    '0.75': 0.40,
    '1': 0.46,
    '1.1': 0.48,
    '1.2': 0.50,
  }
};

function findInArray() {
  var selectedThread = document.getElementById('secondList').value;
  var selectedTurn = document.getElementById('thirdList').value;
  document.getElementById('kvanswer').innerHTML = `Kv = ${threaded[selectedThread][selectedTurn]}`;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <h1 class="calculatorcom">Valve calculations and conversions</h1><br><br>
  <h2>Oventropp valve Kv finder</h2><br>
  <h2 id="kvanswer"></h2>
</div>
<div class="valvetype">
  <select class="form-control" id='firstList' name='firstList' onClick="getValveSize()">
    <option>Type</option>
  </select>
  <select class="form-control" id='secondList' name='secondList' onClick="getTurns()">
    <option>DN</option>
  </select>
  <select class="form-control" id='thirdList' name='thirdList'>
    <option>Turns</option>
  </select>
  <button onclick="findInArray()">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Yeah thats awesome really helpful! Thanks! Can I ask, I want to change the Number of turns on my dropdown list as if the user changes List1 from thread/solder to flange/groove. It just doesnt seem to work. Is there a jQuery way? Or should I post another question?

Comment: You can remove all options from the dropdown with `$('#secondList').find('option').remove()` and then re-add it on selection change of the first dropdown

Comment: hmm not sure if Im doing it correctly I keep losing my dropdown menus. Maybe Im not making the question clear. But List 1 has two options when I choose the second it changes the second list perfectly but it doesnt change the third list correctly??

Comment: But it works in my example? Or do you want to change the options when selecting something on the first dropdown? Then just change the if conditions in the function `getTurns()`

Comment: This might help....
If i choose threaded(list1), DN10- 25(list2) third list changes with turns 0.25 - 7 If i choose flange(list1), DN20-25(list2) third list changes with turns 1-7. Does this make it clearer?

Comment: Thanks for your help but Ive found a solution to this now:1


"Your logic was a bit incorrect previously - The tricky part is that you are checking for flang and 20,25 but the else if is at placed at the end which was never hitting that point.

The threaded option with '10', '15', '20', '25' was placed at first if so that was always becoming true regardless since the condition was matching

Also, you need to use an onchange function NOT an onclick function in your HTML as well. onchange function is used for changing selection or checkboxes." 
Thanks for your help on this.